# How can I implement a feature to change settings?

Tags: 7, features

in our site we have a country field in a registration page of our drupal site. admin can download the all registered users as excel report. I added a new country field in my users.XLS report in data export option at *Structure > Views > Administrator:users* in my development site.

How can I deploy these changes in my staging site(other development site) by using the Features module?
Which feature components can I choose while creating the feature?

Answer (score 1):

1) If you made the changes in only views then only export the view form your local development and import it in your production server

or

2) If you added an new field in content type then goto admin/structure/features/create select the field from FIELD INSTANCES (x) (field_instance) and module will select the dependency automatically then add Name in GENERAL INFORMATION and download and upload it in your module folder and enable it and then follow the 1 point

Note: First try it on your another test development and then on production

Comment: Thanks Shrikant, i tried with first point but it's not given expected result. any other suggestions?